# Use Firebase and Node.js for authenticating user on Android

Tags: android, node.js, firebase

I'm totally lost as to how to do this. I want to be able to authenticate a user with their username and password only--so I have to use a `customAuth` from Firebase.

I created a server (node.js) that handles the generation of tokens (runs on Heroku):

```
var express = require('express')
var Firebase = require('firebase')
var app = express()

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log("Node app is running at localhost:" + app.get('port'))
})

var SECRET = "numbers would be here";

var tokenGenerator = new FirebaseTokenGenerator(SECRET);
var AUTH_TOKEN = tokenGenerator.createToken({
  uid: "arbitrary",
  data: "blahblahblah"});
  console.log(AUTH_TOKEN);

var ref = new Firebase("null");
ref.authWithCustomToken(AUTH_TOKEN, function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Login Succeeded!", authData);
  }
});
```

Now I have an Android app in which I want to authenticate a user. If I have something like,

```
Firebase mRef = new Firebase("myFirebaseUrl");
mRef.authWithCustomToken(String token, AuthResultHandler handler); //issue
```

I don't know how to get the `token`. Furthermore, I'm not sure I understand how it matters if the token is always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to come up with a secure way to communicate the username and password from your Android client to the node.js server and to subsequently communicate the resulting token (or any error codes) back from the node.js server to the client.

While this is definitely possible (it's pretty much how Firebase email+password authentication works), it is definitely too broad a topic to cover in a StackOverflow answer. It's a project, rather than a question.

What you can consider is using Firebase email+password auth and then stubbing out the email domain. So if a user signs up with username `Nxt3` and password, you simply append a dummy domain to the username and register them as `Nxt3@dummydomain.com`.

Comment: That's probably what I'll end up doing; and you're right--this is a broad topic. It's frustrating that I can't find anything online on how to do something like this from start to finish. :\ I appreciate your response, nonetheless.

Comment: If somebody had already done what you're doing start-to-finish, there'd be no need for you to build the app you are building. :-)